# CodeIgniter 4 Upload Images Taken From an iPhone/Android

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have a file upload script built in codeigniter4, I'm trying to allow HEIC file but Codeigniter is returning an error saying this is an unsupported file type.

I've added the HEIC mime type to the mimes.php file inside app/Config and Codeigniter is still throwing the unsupported file type error.

Has anyone been successful in allowing images taken from an iPhone to be uploaded?

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Please read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve it. Otherwise, you risk having it closed since it lacks debugging details.